# Assign 15 people to event from a pool of 550 in an iPhone app

Tags: mobile, iphone

I'm trying to design a way to assign 15 to 20 people to a scheduled event choosing from a pool of around 500 available persons.

Currently, I use one screen that should show number of available slots, persons already assigned to event with remove option & list of all availble persons to choose from among other things. Also, filters and/or search for quickfind functionality. By the length of said list it looks like I will have to use some kind of pagination, too.
I'm trying to keep clicks and pages to minimum but I might have to expand.

I'm guessing this is already a very complex task for a mobile screen UI-wise, but I'd appreciate any feedback like possible page breakdown or suggestions for enormous list display options.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? It's very light on details so we don't have anywhere to start from. More description would help too.

Comment: I'm afraid I've got nothing solid at the moment. I'll post again when I'm close to something.

Comment: I've put the question on hold for the time being until you're able to provide more detail. Once you've done so we can reopen this question for you.

Answer (score 1):

Enormous lists work best with a powerful search. As well as searching by name, allow filtering by other parameters if appropriate. On mobile, almost everything is faster than typing.

For example, searching with a string of two characters and tapping a filter option is much faster than searching for a longer string (>5 characters). However, the list of filters must be immediately accessible.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcDvi1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, this would probably be the better way and I would add that it would be nice to keep the filter in place and have a link or button to the right that would "add to pool" and maybe a count up top that would show a running total of people moved over. Then the row that's been added could be styled some way too. Just my .02 cents. :)